# watchdog writes duplicates in uploading zip file

Tags: python, logging, watchdog

Here is the issue with event on adding file to directory through filebrowser. Loading a single file produce bunch of events:

[image]

I suppose that the number of messages depends on time of uploading zip file.
I can't figure out how it could be resolved with watchdog, here is the code:

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import logging

class Watcher:
    DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = "/input"

    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()

    def run(self):
        event_handler = DataHandler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, recursive=False)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(5000)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print("Error")

        self.observer.join()


class DataHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None
        
        elif event.event_type == "created":
            print(f"Received created event {event.src_path}")

        elif event.event_type == "modified":
            print(f"Received modified event {event.src_path}")

if __name__ ==   "__main__":
    w = Watcher()
    w.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have one event printed for the same file, you can save the last path that was modified and only print the message when the new one is different:

```py
class DataHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    last_path_modified = ""

    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None
        
        elif event.event_type == "created":
            print(f"Received created event {event.src_path}")

        elif event.event_type == "modified":
            if event.src_path != self.last_path_modified:
                print(f"Received modified event {event.src_path}")
                self.last_path_modified = event.src_path
```

Of course, you can adjust this code to match the exact logic you want to apply for your situation, maybe printing it again if it's been flagged x times, or keeping track of the time since the first message and printing it again if it's been more than x seconds/minutes since the last message.